# Expected length of longest common substring

Tags: probability, combinatorics

For two strings, a [longest common substring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem) is a substring of maximal length which is common to both strings. For example for $babba$ and $cdddabbd$ a longest common substring is $abb$ which has length $3$.

> Consider two uniformly sampled binary strings, each of length $n$.
>   What is the expected length of a longest common substring?

If we wanted to know the expected longest common prefix length would be $1$.  The length follows the [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution). So we could look at all $1 \leq i, j \leq n$  and try to compute the maximum expected value of all longest common prefixes starting at index $i$ in the first string and index $j$ in the second. I don't know how to complete this analysis however.

Comment: According to [this paper by Arratia and Waterman](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0001870885900039), the length of the longest common substring is tightly concentrated around $2\log_2(n)$.